# R WHERE EXISTS-type subsetting?

Tags: r

In `SQL`, you can limit a query result with a `WHERE EXISTS` qualifier.  For example, this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_B
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A)
```

Can you do the same thing in `R`?

I've got a large dataframe - Call it df.a.

```
str(df.a)
ClientID : Factor w/ 148892 levels
Month    : Date, format  "2012-07-31"
Visits   : int
```

I've subsetted df.a to a smaller df.b.  Now, I want to go back to df.a but only get records if the clientID is in df.b.

I was able to use `merge`, like this, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
july.activity <- merge(df.a, df.b, by="ClientID", all.x=TRUE)
july.activity <- subset(july.activity, Visits.x != "NA")
```

Comment: If `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` are data frames then `library(sqldf); sqldf("SELECT * FROM Table_B WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A)")` would return a data frame with the result. (With this approach do not use data frame names with dots in them since dot is an SQL operator.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this does what you need?

```
july.activity <- df.a[df.a$ClientID %in% df.b$ClientID & !is.na(df.a$Visits), ]

df.a <- data.frame(ClientID = factor(letters[c(1,2,2,3)]), Visits = c(1,NA,2,3))
df.b <- df.a[1:2,]
df.b
  ClientID Visits
1        a      1
2        b     NA
df.a
  ClientID Visits
1        a      1
2        b     NA
3        b      2
4        c      3
df.a[df.a$ClientID %in% df.b$ClientID & !is.na(df.a$Visits), ]
  ClientID Visits
1        a      1
3        b      2
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 results when I run that.  I've never used `in` before, so I want to look at the documentation.  However, the word in is very common, so searching isn't helping.  Can you point me in the right direction to read about it?

Comment: You can begin with ?'%in%'. Just note that a %in% b and b %in% a are not the same.

Comment: @mikebmassey, if you are still getting nothing (is it NA's or what?) when you run this, then I would say that something must be wrong with `df.b` and that would be good to see how did you get and modified it.